# Static class doesn't get called first but instance class. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, static

I am aware that, static constructors always take precedence and get called first before any instance constructors. However consider the scenario of me having one instance class and one static class. I am wondering why the results are first from Base class and then static class ? I have also verified interchanging calling, I get the result accordingly. But am I wrong in my thoughts that, Static classes always should be called first irrespective of any other instance classes ? Why this raised to me is because, I saw somewhere that, Static classes are loaded automatically when the namespace containing that class is triggered. Then I would expect that static constructor to fire first. Why not it is happening ? Could someone please explain in an understandable and simple way.

```
    public class Base
    {
        public Base() { Console.WriteLine(" I am from normal Base constructor"); }
        static Base() { Console.WriteLine("Hey I am from Static Base"); } 
    }
    public static class Base1
    {
        static Base1() { Console.WriteLine("I am from Static Constructor"); }
        public static void StaticMethod() { Console.WriteLine("I am from Static Method");   }            
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base b = new Base();
        Base1.StaticMethod();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Just where did you read Static classes are loaded automatically when the namespace containing that class is triggered?

Comment: "I saw somewhere that, Static classes are loaded automatically when the namespace containing that class is triggered." How do you "trigger" a namespace? This does not make sense. Please post a link to the mysterious "somewhere", it's not clear what they meant.

Comment: Hi Blam and dasb, sorry if I have misunderstood, but you can see the similar statement in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: That link does say "Static classes are loaded automatically by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program or namespace containing the class is loaded."

Comment: Uhmm yes. Honestly, I don't understand this statement still. I understood the way someone explained below, but I find difficulty understanding what MSDN is trying to convey in the above statement.

Comment: Depends on the definition of "loaded".  I think they just mean available / assigned.  Base1.StaticMethod() is valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static constructors are only called if they are actually needed. If they are needed, they are guaranteed to be called before the normal constructors for their class.

But there is no guarantee that all static constructors will be called before any normal constructor for a different class.

It wouldn't be possible to do that AND avoid calling static constructors that aren't used. You could do something like only access a class with a static constructor just before the program terminates, and then only if some condition was satisfied. Clearly, the code couldn't peer ahead in time to determine whether or not the static constructor call would be needed; therefore, there is no way for it to call the static constructor before your code accesses it.

Check out [Eric Lippert's Blog about Static Constructors](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/06/static-constructors-part-one/) for many more details!

Answer (score 1):

There is only one guarantee:

> The static constructor of a class is called before any instance constructor or any static member of that class.

This guarantee doesn't say anything about the time the static constructor is invoked. Most of the times, it will be invoked when the static class actually is being used - and not earlier.

There is no reason for the static constructor to be executed before you create an instance of *another* class.

You say:

> I saw somewhere that, Static classes are loaded automatically when the namespace containing that class is triggered.

That is not correct, I think you may have misunderstood something there.

The MSDN states the following:

> Static classes are loaded automatically by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program or namespace containing the class is loaded.

I see how this can be misunderstood. "Loading a class" here doesn't mean that its constructor is executed. It means that the CLR simply loads the type and performs some verification on it.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes I may have misunderstood the statement given in MSDN :( I am not quite comfortable with MSDN explanations most times. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Oh now your explanation makes me understand that statement by MSDN. I thought, loading means, firing the constructors too. Many thanks for explaining me :) :)

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN:

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to
>   perform a particular action that needs performed once only. It is
>   called automatically before the first instance is created or any
>   static members are referenced.

So in your case - first you are calling Base class constructor, then you're accessing Base1 static method.

Answer (score 0):

A static constructor is called before you create an instance of your class or you access one of its static methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx), so the result you are getting is correct.